# How to draw the Small logo type image at Right-Bottom corner of the canvas?

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, android-emulator, android-widget

In My application i use canvas to do paint.
Now in this application i want to Draw the Little small logo image at the right-bottom corner of the canvas before saving it in to Bitmap.
So how to make it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Some googling and searching for code, i got the answer of my question:
I Use this function to got the Image at the right-bottom corner.

```
 public static Bitmap addLogo(Bitmap mainImage, Bitmap logoImage) { 
    Bitmap finalImage = null; 
        int width, height = 0; 
        width = mainImage.getWidth(); 
        height = mainImage.getHeight(); 
        finalImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, mainImage.getConfig()); 
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(finalImage); 
        canvas.drawBitmap(mainImage, 0,0,null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(logoImage, canvas.getWidth()-logoImage.getWidth() ,canvas.getHeight()-logoImage.getHeight() ,null);

        return finalImage; 
}
```

Hope this code help to anyother.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, try

```
context.drawImage(img_elem, x, y);
```

to insert your image (where img_elem is your image reference and x/y are your destination coordinates).

To use x and y, depending where you wish to insert the image, try something like:

```
x = canvasWidth-25;
y = canvasHeight-25;
```

To place it in the bottom right corner.

Then, convert to an image as per normal:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: Please see my answer. I got the sollution.

Comment: Except you're drawing the bitmap, then drawing the logo on top of the bitmap.

Your question asked how to do draw it ON the canvas before making it a bitmap.

Essentially your code does what I wrote above, and I'm glad it worked for you, but you're not directly inserting into the canvas (though I doubt that matters in your case).